# which code block to write and where to reach and assign?

Tags: c#

which code block to write and where to reach and assign?
hi to all sorry for the basic question but i will be happy if you can explain some Qs below. thanks.

```
 namespace forms
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // in thic code block what kind of things can i write or im allowed to write?   Q1
        }

        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();  // why should i write this line (since i already added form2 to my project as seen in the picture) ![enter image description here][1]to see frm2.Show(); in button1_Click part?   Q2
        //what happens in the background (from the compiler point of view) when i do Form2 frm2 = new Form2();?   Q3

        frm2.Show(); // why cant i reach frm2 in here? i just declared above.  Q4
        //just like that
        int number1; // i declare number variable in here
        number1= 5; // and why cant i assign number in here?

        // what kind of things can i write or allowed to write in this block ?   Q5
        // i sometimes confuse where i need to start writing the code or where i need to write or in which block ?

        public int number2;

        // ok now lets say i put a button on the form and when i double click it generated the code down below 
        //and now lets look in that code block

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
           // ok now we are in this block and now it see when i write 
           frm2.Show();
            //or 
            //it see when i write 
           number1 = 5;   
           //ok now lets look at number1 and number2 what changes when i write public int and just int without public?  Q6
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the error for row #23?

Comment: you can read the code and questions above. actually there is no problem but i did this way as an exercise to come up with questions and to get answers so that i can enlighten more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your code shouldn't compile on line:

```
frm2.Show();
```

and

```
number1= 5;
```

These lines should be part of a method.

Now to your questions.

Q1. That's the constructor block of `Form1` class. You may do initialization and other stuff you want to be executed on first execution of the `Form1`.

Q2. Your line

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

is creating an instance for `Form2`, although you add the file to the project, to use `Form2` you have to create an instance of it first.

Q3. The above line is creating an instance of `Form2`, calling the constructor for `Form2` and assigning the the instance of `Form2` to its reference `frm2`

Q4. You can't do `frm2.Show();`, Only field definition and initialization can be done at class level. This line should be part of some method.

Q5. Same answer as Q4

Edit:
Q6. If you specify `public` with int, that field will be accessible outside the class, and if you don't specify anything then it is [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) by default.

Comment: so for your answer of Q1 it is like the Main() funcktion in C++ right? and how about for Q6 what changes when i write public int and just int without public?

Comment: @modestandcutegirl, not really, Main is the entry point in program, from Constructor see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: thanks and if you dont mind what you say for Q6. thanks in advance.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl, check the edited part of the answer

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you get a good C# Ebook, e.g. [Visual C# Programming - How to Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132151421).

The questions you ask are covered under the [Constructors](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Objects#Constructors), [Objects](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Objects), [Variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Variables), [Class Accessibility](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Classes) in C#. Also, there's a good number of [free c# books online](http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/listing.php?category=12).

Comment: thanks for referring to the topics and ebooks.

Comment: i voted up your reply for that reason.